# Solution methods for this Weighted Partial Set Cover-ish problem

Tags: optimization, np-complete, integer-programming, set-cover

Given a set of subsets $S_1, ..., S_N$ of a finite universe $E$ of elements $e_1, ..., e_n$ and mapping of those elements to an integer 'weight' $w_1, ... w_n$, select the subset of subsets which maximizes the total contained weight. The empty set has a combined weight of zero.

Note: many weights are negative and the subsets often overlap (or are proper subsets), also importantly the weights are on *elements* - not sets, that is: once an element is included its weight is only counted once. I am able to reduce the 'set cover' problem to this one through a simple construction. That is, I've already shown that this problem is NP-Complete.

I am asking two things:

- Is this problem already studied or discussed in the literature? Does it have a well-known name, and do references exist and if so what are they?
- Do you have ideas relating to practical solution methods, or approximation techniques, for large instances of this problem. $|E|$ in the tens or hundreds of millions, and $|S|$ potentially much larger?

---

I have already modified the standard 'set cover' greedy heuristic to this problem but of course it can fail. For example:

If $E = \{a, b, c\}$ and $S = \{\{a, b\}, \{b, c\}\}$, and the weights are $a \rightarrow 2, b \rightarrow -3, c \rightarrow 2$, then the correct answer is to take both sets for a total value of $1$, even though each set has a sort of pseudo-value of $-1$. The positive valued elements generally need to 'share' the load of the negative valued elements in order to obtain a solution.

---

I have developed the following integer programming formulation, although commercial solvers do not seem to like it very much when the number of sets and elements are very large. We'll call the set of all elements $E$ indexed with $e$, the set of all sets $S$ indexed with $s$ and two sets of subsets: $\hat{S}_e$ are all of the sets of which element $e$ is a member, and then $\bar{E}_s$ are the elements in set $s$. We have two variables $X_e$ 1 if element $e$ is selected, and then $Y_s$ 1 if set $s$ is selected.

$max \sum\limits_{e \in E} w_e X_e$

$s.t. \quad S_s \le X_\bar{e} \quad \forall s \in S, \bar{e} \in \bar{E}_s$

$\quad X_e - \sum\limits_{\hat{s} \in \hat{S}_e} S_{\hat{s}} \le 0 \quad \forall e \in E$

$ X_e, S_s \; binary \quad \forall e \in E, s \in S$

I will note that if you relax the second constraint via lagrangian relaxation you have a max flow problem which is very nice.